# BDD running a scenario with examples in parallel

Tags: selenium, junit, bdd

Let us say we have a story file like this:

```
Scenario: Looking up the definition of a word 
Given the user does not know the meaning of the word word 
When the user looks up the definition of the word word 
Then they should obtain a definition containing the words definition    

Examples: | word              | definition 
          | apple             | A common, round fruit                     
          | banana            | An elongated curved fruit                
          | pear              | An edible fruit produced by the pear tree
```

Is there a way to run this scenario in 3 different threads at the same time, for every example? Without creating three different story files?